# Is it ok to use C# Property like this

Tags: c#, .net

One of my fellow developer has a code similar to the following snippet

```
class Data
{
     public string Prop1
     {
           get
           {
                // return the value stored in the database via a query
           }
           set
           {
                // Save the data to local variable
           }
     }

     public void SaveData()
     {
          // Write all the properties to a file
     }

}

class Program
{
    public void SaveData()
    {
         Data d = new Data();
         // Fetch the information from database and fill the local variable
         d.Prop1 = d.Prop1; 
         d.SaveData();
    }
}
```

Here the Data class properties fetch the information from DB dynamically. When there is a need to save the Data to a file the developer creates an instance and fills the property using self assignment. Then finally calls a save. I tried arguing that the usage of property is not correct. But he is not convinced.

This are his points

1. There are nearly 20 such properties.
2. Fetching all the information is not required except for saving.
3. Instead of self assignment writing an utility method to fetch all will have same duplicate code in the properties.

Is this usage correct?

Comment: 'Correct' is fairly subjective, but I don't think you'll find many people who'll argue his way.

Comment: Why is d.Prop1 set to itself?  Is this to trigger some kind of 'dirty' flag so it knows what to save when SaveData() is called?

Comment: What is the complexity of the fetches: are all 20 values trivial reads from a single table, or are the computed, distributed across tables, etc.?

Comment: @Grant: no, that's the abuse here; the get and set do entirely different things. That's storing a local copy of a value read from the database.

Comment: @Rup oh yeah, sorry I didn't read the comments in there.  Just goes to show, self-commenting code is very important!  Which is just one reason I'd say this is a BAD IDEA.

Comment: To give little bit more information. I was convinced with the lazy loading of data from the DB beacuse majority of the time the client needs very few information. There are lot of classes that model the data in the DB. The size of DB also is pretty huge. So there is no point in loading all the data in the constructor and keeping it ready. But the implementation of lazy loading using a property like above was the concern to me. Anyway thanks to all for taking the time and answering.

Comment: @Grant Also shows reading the comments can be very important

Comment: @DrDro - sure, reading comments is probably a very good idea on a Q&A site!  But as we all know, comments are often out of date or incorrect, and the code is the only real truth, so I think I've got into the habit of ignoring them.  I think in general, that's not a bad strategy.

Comment: @Grant I was just being funny. I understand your point of view about comments in general but I would tend to say that it's the first place to go when you encounter something weird. And I'm sure you usually do it, naturally.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think that another developer who will work with the same code will be happy to see :

```
d.Prop1 = d.Prop1;
```

Personally I would never do that.

Also it is not the best idea to use property to load data from DB.
I would have `method` which will load data from DB to local variable and then you can get that data using property. Also `get/set` logically must work with the same data. It is strange to use `get` for getting data from DB but to use `set` to work with local variable.

Comment: Ah, that was not a typo? Well spotted :). Thought it meant something like `string exampleOfFirstUseGettingProperty = d.Prop1`.

Answer (score 4):

Properties should really be as lightweight as possible.

When other developers are using properties, they expect them to be intrinsic parts of the object (that is, already loaded and in memory).

The real issue here is that of symmetry - the property get and set should mirror each other, and they don't. This is against what most developers would normally expect.

Having the property load up from database is not recommended - normally one would populate the class via a specific method.

Comment: I don't completely agree: I don't see any problem with lazily read properties (if not read yet, get loads all data then returns) assuming that's the general convention in your code and provided the object has enough state to do this and there are sensible error cases. However I think the real problem is that the property get and set are not opposite actions here.

Comment: Agreed.
@ferosekhanj: In my experience loading one entity with 20 fields does not take much longer than loading just one field of the entity. Maybe you're micro-optimizing too much here.

Comment: Don't do this. Getting the values in the constructor causes a risk (no exceptions in ctors, that's dangerous) and can quickly become a performance drain (nothing lightweight when you have an array of Data), unless you take care of it through a singleton. If you want to keep it this simple, create a RetrieveData, and/or a flag that you can test in the gettor.

Comment: Also not the best Idea to load data from DB in constructor.

Answer (score 3):

"Correct" is often in the eye of the beholder. It also depends how far or how brilliant you want your design to be. I'd never go for the design you describe, it'll become a maintenance nightmare to have the CRUD actions on the POCOs.

Your main issue is the absense of ***separations of concerns***. I.e., The data-object is also responsible for storing and retrieving (actions that need to be defined only once in the whole system). As a result, you end up with duplicated, bloated and unmaintainable code that may quickly become real slow (try a LINQ query with a join on the gettor).

A common scenario with databases is to use small entity classes that only contain the properties, nothing more. A DAO layer takes care of retrieving and filling these POCOs with data from the database and defined the CRUD actions only ones (through some generics). I'd suggest NHibernate for the ORM mapping. The basic principle explained here works with other ORM mappers too and is [explained here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx).

The reasons, esp. nr 1, should be a main candidate for refactoring this into something more maintainable. Duplicated code and logic, when encountered, should be reconsidered strongly. If the gettor above is really getting the database data (I hope I misunderstand that), get rid of it as quickly as you can.

Overly simplified example of separations of concerns:

```
class Data 
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}

class Dao<T>
{
    SaveEntity<T>(T data)
    {
        // use reflection for saving your properies (this is what any ORM does for you)
    }
    IList<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        // use reflection to retrieve all data of this type (again, ORM does this for you)
    }
}

// usage:
Dao<Data> myDao = new Dao<Data>();
List<Data> allData = myDao.GetAll();
// modify, query etc using Dao, lazy evaluation and caching is done by the ORM for performance
// but more importantly, this design keeps your code clean, readable and maintainable.
```

EDIT:
One question you should ask your co-worker: what happens if you have many Data (rows in database), or when a property is a result of a joined query (foreign key table). Have a look at [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) if you want a smooth transition from one situation (unmaintainable) to another (maintainable) that's easy enough to understand by anybody.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty terrible, imo.

1. Properties are supposed to be quick / easy to access; if there's really heavy stuff going on behind a property it should probably be a method instead.
2. Having two utterly different things going on behind the same property's getter and setter is very confusing. `d.Prop1 = d.Prop1` *looks* like a meaningless self-assignment, not a "Load data from DB" call.
3. Even if you do have to load twenty different things from a database, doing it this way *forces* it to be twenty different DB trips; are you sure multiple properties can't be fetched in a single call? That would likely be much better, performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would write a serialize / deserialize function, then provide properties as lightweight wrappers around the in-memory results.

Take a look at the ISerialization interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This would be very hard to work with,

If you set the Prop1, and then get Prop1, you could end up with different results
eg:

```
//set Prop1 to "abc"
d.Prop1 = "abc";

//if the data source holds "xyz" for Prop1
string myString = d.Prop1;
//myString will equal "xyz"
```

reading the code without the comment you would expect mystring to equal "abc" not "xyz", this could be confusing.

This would make working with the properties very difficult and require a save every time you change a property for it to work.

Comment: Thanks to all the people for answering. I agree with @esde84 that the symmetry will be lost if a property is implemented like this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that's an awful design. Using a property getter to do some "magic" stuff makes the system awkward to maintain. If I would join your team, how should I know that magic behind those properties?

Create a separate method that is called as it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

As well as agreeing with what everyone else has said on this example, what happens if there are other fields in the Data class? i.e. Prop2, Prop3 etc, do they all go back to the database, each time they are accessed in order to "return the value stored in the database via a query". 10 properties would equal 10 database hits. Setting 10 properties, 10 writes to the database. That's not going to scale.

Comment: The rationale behind such property implementation is the client who is using this class doesn't access all the porperties. So the property does a lazy loading of those properties that are required.

Comment: I suppose that's extremely lazy loading. I've only used lazy loading for properties that need to load child "records" (multiple) from a related table (like reading the order detail lines when the LineItems property of an order is read) - never one value at a time from the same table as other information.